# Flex Mobile Project - White Screen when the the pushView is called

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air, project

can someone help me?
Well, my app have a button, and when you click on this button, this call a function that have a line navigator.pushView(); But, before to load the second view, appear one white screen , and then, my second view is loaded. Can i remove this white screen?

myFirstView

> 

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import classes.utilis;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.states.Transition;

        var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000);

        private function init(event:FlexEvent):void{
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, utilis.getInstance().checkKeys);
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, utilis.getInstance().checkKeys);
            loading.visible = true;
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, loginPage);
            myTimer.start();
        }

        private function loginPage(event:TimerEvent):void{
            myTimer.stop();
            myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, loginPage);
            //VERIFICAR AQUI SE ELE JÁ POSSUI LOGIN ATRIBUIDO E JÁ REDIRECIONAR PARA A ÁREA DO USUÁRIO.
            navigator.pushView(telaLogin);
        }



    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Image left="-15" right="-15" top="-12" bottom="-4" horizontalCenter="0" scaleMode="stretch"
         smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high" source="assets/someHDImage.png"
         verticalCenter="-4"/>
<!-- para dar uma borda arredondada ao layout-->
<s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" 
        radiusX="10" radiusY="10">

    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" color="#696969" weight="2" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>
<!-- para dar uma borda arredondada ao layout-->
<s:BusyIndicator id="loading" left="130" width="15%" height="10%" horizontalCenter="0"
                 verticalCenter="-34"
                 visible="true"
                 symbolColor="red"
                 />
```

My second View

> 

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import classes.utilis;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        var tfLoading:TextFormat;


        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            backgroundImage.source="assets/casal-apaixonado-na-praia22.png";
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeys);
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeys);
            lblLoading.text = "";
        }
        public function checkKeys(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
            switch(event.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.BACK:
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                    break;
                case Keyboard.MENU:
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case Keyboard.SEARCH:
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    break;
            }
        }
        protected function btnSairClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //Desenvolver um ALERT para confirmar com o usuário.
            utilis.getInstance().textDialog = "Você tem certeza que deseja sair?";
            utilis.getInstance().retDialog = false;
            utilis.getInstance().actionDialog = "sair";
            navigator.pushView(telaDialog);
        }
        protected function btnLoginClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            lblLoading.setStyle("color", "red");
            if(txtLogin.text == ""){
                lblLoading.text = "Você precisa preencher o Login";
                txtLogin.setFocus();
            }else if(txtSenha.text == ""){
                lblLoading.text = "Você precisa preencher a Senha";
                txtSenha.setFocus();
            }else{
                lblLoading.setStyle("color", "green");
                lblLoading.text = "Por favor aguarde...";

                //Efetuar o Login, Salvar para da próxima vez não precisar mais e redirecionar para a telaAreaUsuario
                navigator.pushView(telaAreaUsuario);

            }

        }

        protected function btnCadastroClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            navigator.pushView(telaCadastro);               
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";


</fx:Style>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button width="50" height="40" icon="assets/sair.png" click="btnSairClick(event)"/>
</s:actionContent>
<s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" contentBackgroundAlpha="0.4" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">

    <s:Image id="backgroundImage" left="-15" right="-15" top="-12" bottom="-4" horizontalCenter="0" scaleMode="stretch"
         smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high" source="assets/someHDImage.png"
         verticalCenter="-4"/>

<!-- para dar uma borda arredondada ao layout-->
<s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" 
        radiusX="10" radiusY="10">

    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" color="#696969" weight="2" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>


    <!-- para dar uma borda arredondada ao layout-->
    <s:Scroller left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" horizontalCenter="-5" verticalCenter="0">

        <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">

            <s:TextInput id="txtLogin" y="61" left="30" right="57" horizontalCenter="-14"/>
            <s:Label x="10" y="38" text="Login"/>
            <s:Label x="10" y="121" text="Senha"/>
            <s:TextInput id="txtSenha" y="143" left="30" right="57" horizontalCenter="-14" displayAsPassword="true"/>
            <s:Label id="lblLoading" x="4" y="196" width="100%" text="Efetue o login!" textAlign="center"/>

            <s:Button right="35" top="210" width="50" height="50" click="btnLoginClick(event)" icon="/assets/btlogin.png"/>
            <s:Label right="4" top="275" click="btnCadastroClick(event)" color="#0E16C3"
                     fontSize="12" text="Quero me cadastrar" textDecoration="underline"
                     useHandCursor="true"/>

        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>

</s:Group>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Post some of your code and describe *exactly* what you're expecting and what's going wrong.

Comment: Brian, thank you for the comments. Well, my app have a button, and when you click on this button, this call a function that have a line
navigator.pushView();
But, before to load the second view, appear one white screen , and then, my second view is loaded. Can i remove this white screen?

Comment: Without seeing the second view, primarily the constructor and `createChildren` functions or the layout, there isn't much we can do for you here. It'd also be great to know how you are testing (i.e. on device, in AIR simulator, what device, etc)

Comment: Josh, i'm testing on my device and on simulator too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Main.mxml file in /src  folder You have to add black background. My Main file looks like: 
(I have black background on pushing views)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                            firstView="views.Start" 
                            splashScreenImage="MySplashScreen" 
                            backgroundColor="black">

</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```